# Eclipse 2023-09 crashes whenever Javadocs begin loading

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, javadoc

Eclipse is instant-crashing with no errors, no warnings whenever Javadocs are loaded.

This happens during:

- content-assist with <kbd>CTRL+SPACE</kbd> (the content-assist part is working fine, however, when hovering over a method, a second panel opens that has the Javadoc: it is when this second panel begins to open when the crash occurs)
- whenever the Javadoc Eclipse view is opened (even if nothing is selected, simply opening the view panel causes the crash)

The crash happens immediately.
Nothing is shown on the screen, nothing is written to the logs, program just stops and vanishes.
Everything restarts just fine, however *(workspace does not save, and reverts back to whatever previous state it had)* and I can continue working.

Have already tried:

- updating/validating/removing the location of the Javadoc for the the Installed JREs
- changing/disabling the internal/external Web Browser
- updating the `eclipse.ini` file with various options for `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser`, based on various crash bug reports, most of which were extremely old to begin with
- checking the logs in `/confuguration/` and `/.metadata/.log`

(Unfortunately, there is nothing in any of the logs.)

Installation is totally vanilla. There are no plugins installed, and no configuration changes from the installation defaults.

```
Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
Build ID: 4.29.0.20230907-1200
Platform: Debian Linux
```

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA GPU with an NVIDIA driver? Does it also crash on _Help > Help Contents_? If yes, it's related to the web browser widget. When you start Eclipse in the terminal, is then anything logged/printed?

Comment: Ah ha! "No provider of eglCreateImage found.  Requires one of: EGL 15" (yes, it does crash on Help > Help Contents)

Comment: And there is already a bug report: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/8013

Comment: Does the [workaround that is mention it that bug report work for you (setting the environment variable `WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1`)](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/8013#issuecomment-1761085938)? If yes, please add a self-answer.

Comment: Once I remembered to tack the `env` on the front of the command, it worked great! Thank you for those who responded!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From information provided in this [bug report](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/8013), launching Eclipse with a modified environment variable solved the problem.

```
env WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 ./eclipse
```